# Android Extended Toolbar with EditTexts

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar

I am trying to implement a tollbar similar to the one seen here:
[image]

I also want to have a title at the top of the toolbar which I don't seem to be able to do with my current layout.

My current toolbar layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:float="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/new_monitor_toolbar"
android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <!-- Toolbar space -->
    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"/>

    <com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext.FloatLabeledEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            style="@style/EditTextHeadline"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:hint="Name"/>

    </com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext.FloatLabeledEditText>

    <!-- First divider space -->
    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="8dp"/>


    <com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext.FloatLabeledEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        float:fletTextAppearance="@style/floatlabelededittext">

        <EditText
            style="@style/EditTextSubhead"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="12dp"
            android:paddingTop="12dp"
            android:hint="URL"/>

    </com.wrapp.floatlabelededittext.FloatLabeledEditText>

    <!-- Second divider space -->
    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="16dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

My Activity:

```
 Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.new_monitor_toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle( "New Page Monitor" );
        Toast.makeText(this, "Should have title", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I also am not sure how to get the back arrow to show up properly.  Any help would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First off, do you know that the Toolbar returned by `findViewById()` isn't null? It's concerning that the Toolbar you specified is not in the layout of your entire activity. I would recommend that the Toolbar layout and the Activity layout are all in one layout file, or at the very least, you include the Toolbar layout in your activity layout. To put a title in your Toolbar, I'd recommend adding a TextView to your layout. As for the back arrow showing up, `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` should do the trick.

Comment: The toolbar I specified is in the layout of my acttivty.  The layout posed above is just the toolbar layout that is included in the main activity.

Comment: Can you put  a Log statement inside your if statement to make sure the Toolbar isn't null?

Answer (score 0):

[android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/Toolbar.html) does not have a `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()` function. Use `toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.ic_drawer)` instead.

As for the title, change

```
<!-- Toolbar space -->
<Space
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"/>
```

to

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:text = "Your title"/>
```